# Placing an image in button but it does not show image

Tags: java, android-studio, button

I created a button and I used `android:background="@drawable/background"` to change the image however it only displays the default design of a button (purple). How do I set it to the image I have saved in my drawable folder?

I know there is Image Button but I wanted to write a text on the button, but there is no feature where I can write a text on top if I used Image Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you can't put a text if you have used `ImageButton`.

As far as I understood, you want to have view which has a **text on above of image** and **image on bottom of the text**.

If you use `android:background` feature on `Button`, button's background will be your drawable image and it won't be as you have expected.

If you are going to use `Button` for sure, you can use `android:drawableBottom` feature to show your drawable image on below of your text. And you can basically add button text by using `android:text` feature.

My advice to you, you should use `TextView` instead of `Button` for that case. Because if you do it with the `Button` as I have mentioned above, your button will have background and you can make transparent background for your button by using below code.

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMoreTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

This code will make your `Button` has a transparent background.

```xml
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

But this is a little bit hacky solution. If it won't have background and if you do not have to use `Button` in your case for sure, you can use `TextView` for that and basically to show text and drawable on bottom, you can code your `TextView` basically as below.

```xml
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    app:drawableBottomCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24" />
```

**Note:** These are very simple xml examples to solve your main problem about showing image on bottom of your text, in same view. If you need anything more, let me know and I would be glad to help.